# Apply ko bindings to partial view

Tags: knockout.js, partial-views

I have a ko viewmodel. I want to render a partial view twice on the same page. Once for physical address and once for postal address. They have the same properties, the data is just different. There is no client side knockout parent view model which contains both physical and postal addresses. I'm getting the "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." Extract below. I  could create a knockout model called addresses which will contain both physical and postal and then use the with binding in a partial with 2 divs (one for postal, one for physical). I'm guessing that will work. But i don't really want to create a parent model unless necessary.Any suggestions?

Page:

```
@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.PhysicalAddress)
@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.PostalAddress)
```

Partial:

```
@model Models.AddressDetailsViewModel
<div id="myDiv">
        <table class="my-table">
                <tr>
                    <td id="postalCode">
                        <span data-bind="text: props.postalCode">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>               
        </table>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    var viewModel = mapAddress(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#myDiv")[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: try cleanNode(//divid) and re-apply bindings . have you given that a try

Comment: As id should be unique it's not valid to have the same ids twice on the same page like that.

Comment: @WayneEllery If i don't explicitly set ids should that work?

Comment: Nope, it will just make your html valid. Have you tried applying bindings at the parent level rather than in the partial view?

Comment: @WayneEllery I was trying to avoid that, but it seems to be the best option. Thanks

Comment: Just noticed looking back at this question that your partial view has `id="...."` in it. If the view is single-use that's fine, but using the view multiple times might cause issues since there would be duplicate IDs. This is one thing Knockout is good at helping with, since you bind via HTML and not by ID. Very few of my pages have any ID tags on them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `with` binding in Knockout to bind parts of a ViewModel to a reusable partial view. I wrote a blog article about this a while back:

https://conficient.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/knockout-multiple-viewmodels-and-reusable-partial-views/

I actually used addresses as the example in my sample code so you should find this helps a lot. In your sample you would do it this way:

```
<div data-bind="with: physicalAddress">
    @Html.Partial("_Address")
</div>

<div data-bind="with: postalAddress">
    @Html.Partial("_Address")
</div>
```

This assumes that the two DIVs are within the main ViewModel binding context. Note that if either address is undefined or null, the address HTML won't be visible.

Knockout version 3.2 introduced the concept of components as @shailendra-kumar has also pointed out. In the longer term, this is a better approach, but partial views should also work.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Knockout Components which was introduced in 3.2.0 version.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html

Create the Knockout component and send the data in parameters once for physical address and once for postal address.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a knockout parent model with a physical and postal address on it. And then I apply bindings on the parent page like so:

```
<div id="physicalAddress">
    @Html.Partial("_Address")
</div>

<div id="postalAddress">
    @Html.Partial("_Address")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
var viewModel = mapParentViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel.viewModels().physicalAddress(), $("#physicalAddress")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel.viewModels().postalAddress(), $("#postalAddress")[0]);</script>
```